# When can we say "I know her"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-usage

The Oxford dictionary says

> **[know somebody/something](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/know_1?q=know)** to be familiar with a person, place, thing, etc.

What does "**to be familiar with**" mean?

When can we say "**I know her**"?

Say, Tom and a woman live in different flats in a block and they look at each other a few times so they can recognize each other's face if they happen to meet on a street.

However, they've never talked together.

Can Tom say "**I know her**"?

Comment: We say "I know her by sight" in such cases. You recognise her but are not personally acquainted.

Comment: It's not always clear. Lawyer to witness: "Do you kow the defendant?" Witness: "Well, we met a few times, but I wouldn't say I really know her . . ."

Comment: Very often "I know her" is used to express quite deep knowledge of a person to the point that you can predict their actions. As in, "I know her; she would never do something like that."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always hard for dictionaries to define very common words. There are no simpler words use as a gloss.

Knowing someone usually means you can recognise them as an individual.  Often it means you can associate a name with a face, or sometimes just that you recognise the face and can associate it with a description of the person.

> Police: Do you know this woman (holding photo)
>
> Tom: Yes, She lives in the same apartment block as me, but I don't know her name.

But sometimes it means something deeper:

> On a first date, you should get to know each other.  Talk about interests, hobbies, and family (but not your ex!)

We also use "know of a person" to mean that we don't know them as an individual, but we have been told about them.